# TimePicker in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Since jQuery datepicker has no time to select, I used the following TimeSpan code which returned two dropdownlists for hours (0-23) and minutes (0-59).  This is working fine.  However, I need 12-hour format with AM/PM dropdownlist.

```
 @model TimeSpan


@Html.DropDownList("hours", Enumerable.Range(0, 24)
                       .Select(i => new SelectListItem
                           {
                             Value = i.ToString(),
                             Text = i.ToString(), 
               //Selected = (Model.Hours > 12 ? Model.Hours - 12 : Model.Hours) == i
                             Selected = Model.Hours == i
                           }
                  ))&nbsp;

@Html.DropDownList("minutes", Enumerable.Range(0, 60)
                       .Select(j => new SelectListItem
                           {
                             Value = j.ToString(),
                             Text = j.ToString(), 
                             Selected=Model.Minutes == j
                           }
                  ))
```

I added the following code to display AM/PM dropdownlist. However, I need to modify the code to display 12-hour format with AM/PM dropdownlist:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ampm",  Enumerable.Range(0,2)
   .Select(t =>  new SelectListItem
            {
              Value = t.ToString(),
              Text = (t == 0 ? "AM" : "PM"),                       
              Selected = (Model.Hours > 11 ? 1 : 0) == t
            }  
          ))
```

I need help modifying the below TimeBinder class for 12 hour format with AM/PM dropdownlist.

```
public class TimeBinder : IModelBinder
    {         
        object IModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {            
            //Ensure there's incoming data
            //*************************
            //*** Validate "HOURS"  ***
            //*************************
            var hoursKey = bindingContext.ModelName; //key = EODTime
            var hoursValueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(hoursKey + ".hours"); //valueProviderResult = {15} (for selection of 15:10); RawValue has array of 15           

                if ((hoursValueProviderResult == null) ||
                   string.IsNullOrEmpty(hoursValueProviderResult.AttemptedValue))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                //Preserve it in case we need to redisplay the form
                bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(hoursKey, hoursValueProviderResult);

                //Parse
                var hours = ((string[])hoursValueProviderResult.RawValue)[0];

                //**************************
                //*** Validate "MINUTES" *** 
                //**************************          
                var minuteKey = bindingContext.ModelName; //key = EODTime
                var minutesValueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(minuteKey + ".minutes"); 

                //valueProviderResult = {10} (for selection of 15:10); RawValue has array of 10           

                if ((minutesValueProviderResult == null) ||
                   string.IsNullOrEmpty(minutesValueProviderResult.AttemptedValue))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                //Preserve it in case we need to redisplay the form
                bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(minuteKey, minutesValueProviderResult);

                //Parse           
                var minutes = ((string[])minutesValueProviderResult.RawValue)[0];


                //A TimeSpan represents the time elapsed sice midnight
                var time = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(hours), Convert.ToInt32(minutes), 0);

                return time;

            }  
       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at the following: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

I use it all the time. It's simple, yet powerful as it extends jQueryUI so the theme roller, localization etc. works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you!  I will try this jQuery UI Datepicker.

Comment: @plurby. I am using trents-timepicker. I have no jscript erros on the page. But the picker does not show up. Would you know why? If I put alert inside Timepicker-addon.js, the alert shows up. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: @jaxxbo Did you included jQueryUI (with datepicker and sliders) and timepicker css?

Comment: @plurby Yes I did. I solved the problem. The class name I had put was hasDatepicker. Apparently that was the conflict between DatePicker and TimePicker. As the selector also i was using was ($'hasDatepicker'). But thanks for the reply.